# Proof about connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $p$ a cut point of a connected space $X$ and suppose $A$ and $B$ form a separation of $X-\{p\}$. Prove that $A \cup \{p\}$ is conected.

I only did this: Since $p$ is a cut point then $X-\{ p \}$ is not connected, and since $A$ and $B$ form a separation of $X- \{p \}$ then $X-\{p \} = A \cup B$, and also $A \cup B$ is not connected.

Comment: by separation you mean disjoint open sets?

Comment: @alphaomega Yes I mean that

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints. First prove that for any connected subset $C \subset X$ the closure of is also connected. Then show $A \cup \{p\}$ is the closure of $A$. To do so consider whether $A,B$ are open or closed or neither or both.

Comment: I tried to do it but I couldn't. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\cup \{p\}=C\cup D$ is as separation of $A\cup \{p\}$. Verify that $X=(C\cup D) \cup B$ and that this gives  a separation of $X$. [$C \cup D$ and $B$ are disjoint non-empty open sets in $X$. I am assuming that $\{p\}$ is closed which is true if $X$ is Hausdorff].